# Couchbase System logs enable configuration

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to do Circular log enable for system logs in Couchbase DB but not able to know how to enable.
Reason for doing this that Might be after sometime log size will increase due to huge amount of logs.So I am looking something like after 1 month system log should be overwrite. Is there any suggestion or someone already done this will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any particular setting in the documentations to accomplish exactly this. But you can change the the log file location. So you could create a script that runs monthly that changes the log file location and deletes the logs in the old location.

From the [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/clustersetup/ui-logs.html):

To change the log file configuration:

> 1. Log in as root or sudo and navigate to the directory where you installed Couchbase. For example:
>      /opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config
> 2. Edit the static_config file and change the error_logger_mf_dir variable to a different directory. For example: {error_logger_mf_dir,
>      "/home/user/cb/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs"}
> 3. Restart the Couchbase service. After restarting the Couchbase service, all subsequent logs will be in the new directory.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your reply.Yes I also thought about same but the project requirement is It should not change log location, only kept limit the size of logs and if it goes beyond that it should remove old logs and write the new logs.They have already put some size limitation and number of log file it should kept but I was not able to figure out whether those log file were overwriting or not.

Comment: As Mentioned in Documentation:                                                                                                       Some logs are automatically rotated after a certain fixed size. For example, individual log files are automatically numbered with the number suffix incremented for each new log, and with a maximum of 20 files per log. Individual log file sizes are limited to 10MB by default.

For other logs, when a log file reaches 40MB it will be rotated and compressed. The file will keep 5 rotations (the current rotation plus four compressed rotations).